# problem with gem install mysql on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine

rails version 2.3.5
ruby version 1.8.7

```
PS C:\Ruby187\apps\redmine> gem install mysql
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby
            --with-mysql-dir
            --without-mysql-dir
            --with-mysql-include
            --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
            --with-mysql-lib
            --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
            --with-libmysqllib
            --without-libmysqllib


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a pre-built binary of mysql 2.8.1 gem on rubygems.org:

https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql/versions/2.8.1-x86-mingw32

Unless you're forcing `--platform=ruby` in which case you need MySQL headers and linking libraries.

You also need RubyInstaller DevKit, if that is the Ruby version you're trying to use.

See this post in our group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/msg/8c8ac5f9fe284e8a)

Comment: That is not possible, unless you've manually downloaded mysql-2.8.1.gem file and placed in the same directory where you're invoking gem install, that is the only thing that could trigger this (a local installation)

Comment: i have manually downloaded gem, nothing changes, still same error

Comment: Remove the manual downloaded gems, that I what I'm telling you, it finds mysql-2.8.1.gem, which triggers compilation, remove all the downloaded gem and let the process work remotely. If you're behind a proxy, use gem install --http-proxy option